Java-json-jackson: How to set JsonDeserialize without access to the (abstract) class?
After learning and searching from many examples about deserialization and handling
with a property "type" often used,
(@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type"))
I learned yesterday that if I want to deserialize ALWAYS the same class I can use the following very simple annotation:
@JsonDeserialize(as = SomeInterfaceImplementation.class) within the interface-declaration.
Not so easy to find. But it is exactly what I needed now,
it works well for my situation.
Except in one case:
Unfortunately I have a serialized class java.util.concurrent.Future where I have no access to the source. At least no write-access.
How or better where can I make the annotation to deserialize this always as e.g. MyFutureImpl.class?
The json is serialized with the origin, with java.util.concurrent.Future.
But:

the ObjectMapper throws an exception when I simply do not annotate it. Future has no generic Constructor and cannot be deserialized that way.

When I create my own MyFutureImpl.class, where do I tell the ObjectMapper to use it?


AFAIK JsonDeserialize has to be in the interface or class itself!?
But maybe not. How?
With a "mixin"-solution where I created the following class:

public abstract class FutureMixin {
public FutureMixin(@JsonProperty("cancelled") boolean cancelled, @JsonProperty("done") boolean done)  {
}
private boolean cancelled;
private boolean done;
...

the JsonProperty set (in SearcherStatusResponseImpl.java)

@JsonProperty("future")
private Future future = null;

and to the ObjectMapper added this info:

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(SearcherStatusResponseImpl.class, FutureMixin.class);

I get the following exception:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
construct instance of java.util.concurrent.Future (no Creators, like
default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped
to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional
type information  at [Source: REDACTED
(StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION disabled); line: 1,
column: 239] (through reference chain:
de.jhopmann.BTP.generic.StatusResponseImpl["searcherStatusResponse"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->de.jhopmann.BTP.generic.SearcherStatusResponseImpl["future"])

The ObjectMapper seems not to recognize my setting. Maybe I forget sthg?

You can register your de/serializer for a class directly with the ObjectMapper instance, then you don't need annotations. Or you can register the annotations to a class using a mixin, even if you don't have access to the source code. Both approaches are explained on SO, pick the appropriate one.

Thank you. That's what I am doing, it seems the most examples show it that way. My code is "Object o = mapper.readValue(responseBody, StatusResponseImpl.class);". The root is my StatusResponseImpl and the ObjectMaper is doing it for the class given. But stepping down the JSon I found no way to give more than exactly one class, the entrypoint. WHile looking to the api I am afarid I have to implement my own Subtyperesolver? Hope not. Mixin seems the only way? I have to learn that....

added my result by editing the post. (was too long for comment)
